# after submission a form in PHP $_POST variable is empty, php://input and raw post data also not available

Tags: php, forms, post

After submission a form in smarty template, action form is showing empty array of $_POST

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file("php://input");
var_dump($_POST);
echo "<br/>";

Output :: array(0) { } 

array(0) { } 
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
echo "<br/>";

Output :: array(0) { }
```

Code is working fine on other servers having apache 2.2.X but on system having apache 2.4.4, it is showing nothing in $_POST variable.

Is any need to change in php.ini config file? I already changed post_max_size from 8M to 1000GB but not showing anything

Comment: Confusing! How is the form, anyway ?

Comment: hey why you have changed `post_max_size` from 8M to 1000GB ??? does it makes a sence

Comment: @punk initial I thought that may be due to limitation of post size, it was happening but it was not the reason.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera  above code was in PHP file which is the action page of smarty template. I found the issue , root cause was redirecting the action URL to another URL and resulting the status 302.

Comment: So, the problem solved ? Glad to know that.